# Java reflections - seek a method with specific annotation and its annotation element

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, reflections

Suppose I have this annotation class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MethodXY {
    public int x();
    public int y();
}

public class AnnotationTest {
    @MethodXY(x=5, y=5)
    public void myMethodA(){ ... }

    @MethodXY(x=3, y=2)
    public void myMethodB(){ ... }
}
```

So is there a way to look into an object, "seek" out the method with the @MethodXY annotation, where its element x = 3, y = 2, and invoke it?

This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593597/java-seek-a-method-with-specific-annotation-and-its-annotation-element) using core Java Reflection. I want to know if this can be done using [Reflections 0.9.9-RC1 API](http://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/index.html) without having to iterate over methods using some for loop code or by writing some direct comparision method where I can search the method with given parameters as a key or something.

Comment: What did you try? This question looks *at the moment* too much like a code request

Comment: @RC I have taken set of methods with specified methods using reflections  API but I have to iterate on the set to compare the parameters. i want to avoid the iteration if there is already a method available to the same.

Comment: I'm pretty confident iterating over all annotated methods is mandatory in this case.

Comment: @RC I want something like Reflections#getMethodsAnnotatedWith(MethodXY.class,3,2) if you can suggest something useful

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it with [Reflections#getMethodsAnnotatedWith()](http://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/org/reflections/Reflections.html#getMethodsAnnotatedWith%28java.lang.annotation.Annotation%29).

You can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237289/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-get-an-annotated-method).

Comment: the `Reflections#getMethodsAnnotatedWith()` return set of annoted methods. I want something like `Reflections#getMethodsAnnotatedWith(MethodXY.class,3,2)`

Comment: Using java8:

getMethodsAnnotatedWith(MethodXY.class).stream().filter(method -> method.getAnnotation(MethodXY.class).getX() == 3 && method.getAnnotation(MethodXY.class).getY() == 2).map(method -> method.invoke(this));

This will find all methods with X=3 and Y=2 and invoke them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the thing:

```
public static Method findMethod(Class<?> c, int x, int y) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    for(Method m : c.getMethods()) {
        MethodXY xy = m.getAnnotation(MethodXY.class);
        if(xy != null && xy.x() == x && xy.y() == y) {
            return m;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchMethodException();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    findMethod(AnnotationTest.class, 3, 2).invoke(new AnnotationTest());
    findMethod(AnnotationTest.class, 5, 5).invoke(new AnnotationTest());
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Just want to know if this can be done without me writing the findMethod